# Preserve painting after resize or refresh

Tags: c#, refresh, repaint, flood-fill

How can I preserve the painting I drew on a picturebox?

I draw a circle, and fill it via the ExtFloodFill API.
This works fine.

When I resize the form (or minimize it) and resize it back to its original size part of the painting is gone.

[image: Complete][image: Resized][image: Missing part]

When I refresh the picturebox the painting will be gone completely

I tried to repaint it in the Paint event, but this caused it to be repainted continuously as the painting itself triggered the Paint event as well.

See below for a test project.

- When you click on the picturebox the painting will be drawn.
- When you doubleclick the picturebox will be refreshed.

[1 form with 1 picturebox named pictureBox1]

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace FloodFill
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateSolidBrush(int crColor);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ExtFloodFill(IntPtr hdc, int nXStart, int nYStart, int crColor, uint fuFillType);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y);
        public static uint FLOODFILLSURFACE = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawCircle();
            FillGreen();
        }

        private void DrawCircle()
        {
            Graphics graBox = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle);
            graBox.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, 10, 10, 100, 100);
        }

        private void FillGreen()
        {
            Graphics graBox = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle);
            IntPtr ptrHdc = graBox.GetHdc();
            IntPtr ptrBrush = CreateSolidBrush(ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Green));
            SelectObject(ptrHdc, ptrBrush);
            ExtFloodFill(ptrHdc, 50, 50, GetPixel(ptrHdc, 50, 50), FLOODFILLSURFACE);
            DeleteObject(ptrBrush);
            graBox.ReleaseHdc(ptrHdc);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }

    }
}
```

How can I preserve the painting I make when my form or the picturebox is resized or in any other way to be refreshed?

**[EDIT]**

I changed my Paint event to the following:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawCircle();
        FillGreen();
    }
```

And now the circle is being redrawn after a resized, but the FloodFill isn't

[image: paint event]

(I also gave the picturebox a lightblue background for another test)

**[EDIT2]**

I changed the Paint event to use the Graphics g as follows:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        DrawCircle(g);
        FillGreen(g);
    }

    private void DrawCircle(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, 10, 10, 100, 100);
    }

    private void FillGreen(Graphics g)
    {
        IntPtr ptrHdc = g.GetHdc();
        IntPtr ptrBrush = CreateSolidBrush(ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Green));
        SelectObject(ptrHdc, ptrBrush);
        ExtFloodFill(ptrHdc, 50, 50, GetPixel(ptrHdc, 50, 50), FLOODFILLSURFACE);
        DeleteObject(ptrBrush);
        g.ReleaseHdc(ptrHdc);
    }
```

But when I resize back to the original size some lines of the FloodFill are skipped, especially when I resize slowly

[image: graphics missing lines]

Comment: You need to either draw in or from the paint event using e.Graphics from the Paint params  or into the image bitmap of the picturebox. using a Graphics created from the bitmap! Anything else does not persist as you have seen. I also fail to see why you don't use gdi+ drawing, assuming you are using winforms..

Comment: I come from VB6 and am trying to convert my application to C# ... I edited my question to add a new Paint event I tried, and its result : the circle is now being redrawn but the floodfill isn't

Comment: Could you explain how to use the e.Graphics from the Paint params? And what about gdi+ drawing compared to what I do?

Comment: The resize `Paint` errors can be easily avoided by calling `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` in the form's `Resize` event!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GDI+ methods for drawing the code is simply:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, rect);
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2f))
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen , rect);
    }
}
```

None of your `DllImport` or constants is needed at all.

Note that I chose to use a Pen with a width of 2f to demonstrate the use of the `using` clause to correctly create and dispose of the `GDI+` (non-standard) object `Pen`

This will persist as it is drawn whenever needed. To draw it initially you must call `pictureBox1.Invalidate();`  once!

If you want to change the coordinates you should move the variable `rect` to class level, set it to new data and the call `Invalidate` on the `PictureBox`! The same goes for `Colors` or the `Pen.Width`: use class level variables and after each change trigger the Paint event by calling `Invalidate()`..

Once you understand that, the most important part of learning drawing in `GDI+` is done..

For filling any drawings you have three options:

- simple shapes draw with `DrawXXX` methods all have a `FillXXX` method.
- complex shapes can be created with a `GraphicsPath`, which also has both a `DrawXXX` methods and a `FillXXX` method.
- areas not created by shapes but by drawn pixels must be filled with a floodfill method. There is non buit-in in `GDI+`, but can simply write your own. maybe like [the `Fill4` in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373615/create-custom-shape-for-button/28376826?s=1|0.2667#28376826)..

**Update**: If you feel better using the `FloodFill` from `gdi32.dll` you can do so, but please change the code to use the `Graphics` object from the `Paint` event:

```
   FillGreen(e.Graphics);

private void FillGreen(Graphics graBox)
{
    IntPtr ptrHdc = graBox.GetHdc();
    IntPtr ptrBrush =  CreateSolidBrush(ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Green));
    SelectObject(ptrHdc, ptrBrush);
    ExtFloodFill(ptrHdc, 50, 50, GetPixel(ptrHdc, 50, 50), FLOODFILLSURFACE);
    DeleteObject(ptrBrush);
    graBox.ReleaseHdc(ptrHdc);
}
```

for better flexibility you can probably make the params all dynamic, but I'm not used to that old library..

Note that the **order** of calls **matters**: `FillXXX` wil cover some of the pixels drawn by `DrawXXX`, so it must come first. `FloodFill` however depends on the bounding lines, in your case the circle, being drawn first, so it must come after..

Comment: thanks for the example! ... Eventually I want to draw a bitmap (png file) on the picturebox (or its Graphics), and dynamically fill certain odd-shaped regions of that bitmap ... the fillcolor will depend on data i receive from a via a tcp connection

Comment: for my java applet i did create my own floodfill method which works fine, but in my VB6 program i use the ExtFloodFill API ... the VB6 program is much further developped than the java applet, so i thought of converting that one ... and it was quite easy to use the ExtFloodFill API in VB6 :-)

Comment: The DrawImage method is used for the drawing on a Bitmap. for filling you will probably indeed need a floodfill method, like the one in the link..

Comment: BTW: You also should decide on a basic question: You can draw __onto__ the surface or __into__ the bitmap image of the PictureBox. [See here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337825/picturebox-paintevent-with-other-method/27341797?s=5|0.7547#27341797) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714411/update-a-drawing-without-deleting-the-previous-one/28716887?s=1|0.0000#28716887)

Comment: See my updated answer for using the gdi32.dll call correctly!

Comment: I got the FloodFill working in the paint event on the Graphics, but it somehow skips some lines (especially when i resize slowly) ... I will update my question to show what I mean

Comment: Thanks for all your help and information. I learned a lot here :)