# Count cell in an island with flood fill algorithm

Tags: c#

I have a Matrix[x][y] of ints that are either 1 or 0 in C#. I need to count how many 0 are in an island, and I was thinking of using a flood fill algorithm but I don't know how to write it.
Any ideas?

this is what I did

```
void FloodFill(int r, int c)
{
    player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();

    r = Mathf.RoundToInt(player.coords.x);
    c = Mathf.RoundToInt(player.coords.y);

    if (matrix[r][c] == 1)
    {
        count++; 
        FloodFill(r + 1 , c);
        FloodFill(r , c + 1);
        FloodFill(r - 1 , c);
        FloodFill(r , c - 1);
    }
}
```

I don't think is right though.

Comment: wikipedia is a great resource. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290317/how-can-i-fill-part-of-image-with-color/45299760#45299760)

Answer (score 1):

I will give you the algorithm and leave the coding as exercise.

First create another boolean matrix called `visited[x][y]`

Loop thru the original matrix row by row and whenever you see a 1, you would first check if it has already been visited using the matrix we created above.

If `(a, b)` is not visited then you do `DFS` or `BFS` starting from (a, b) on all neighbor points that are 1. While you are doing this also mark the `visited[a][b] = true`.

When you are done with the `DFS/BFS` for `(a, b)`, increment island count by one and move to `(a + 1, b)`.

You will then have the total count after you have visited `(x, y)`

Total run time: `O(xy)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't need to run thru the entire matrix, I need the algorithm to start inside an island (the start position is taken from another method) and I need to count how many 0s are in that island the 1s being the borders.
I'm using this to check the win condition for a game but I don't know how flood fill works.

Comment: @user10625300 if island inside island is not allowed then you can simply DFS/BFS over all the 0s . simple

Comment: I'm sorry Steve, but I'm new to programming and I'm trying to understand but I can't. I don't know how to write that.

Comment: @user10625300 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search. I would suggest you try this out on a simple setup first. After you are comfortable with DFS you can then try to apply this on your problem

Comment: I wrote this code, I posted in the answer below because it was too long

Comment: @user10625300 as I mentioned before. Try to do DFS on something simple first. Do not apply it on your problem until you understand the whole thing .

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this, how far off am I ?

```
void FloodFill()
{
    player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();

    r = Mathf.RoundToInt(player.coords.x);
    c = Mathf.RoundToInt(player.coords.y);

    Stack cells = new Stack();
    Stack visited = new Stack();

    cells.Push(matrix[r][c]);
    while (cells.Count > 0)
    {
        matrix[r][c] = cells.Pop();  //error cannot convert "object" to "int"

        if (matrix[r][c] == 0)
        {
            visited.Push(matrix[r][c]);
            cells.Push(matrix[r + 1][c]);
            cells.Push(matrix[r][c + 1]);
            cells.Push(matrix[r - 1][c]);
            cells.Push(matrix[r][c - 1]);
        }
    }
    visited.Count();   //error "Stack.Count" cannot be used as a method
    return;
}
```

I know that I'm missing something to check if the cell have been visited, and there are errors that i don't know how to addres