# Incorrect pixel color acquisition or setting

Tags: c#, colors, bitmap, flood-fill

There is a simple implementation of FloodFill algorithm that should fill with red color a black-outlined figure.

```
static void FloodFill(Bitmap bmp, Color color, int i, int j)
        {
            if (i >= 0 && i < bmp.Width - 1 && j >= 0 && j < bmp.Height - 1)
            {
                int c = bmp.GetPixel(i, j).ToArgb();
                int curColorARGB = color.ToArgb();
                int blackColorARGB = Color.Black.ToArgb();

                if (c != blackColorARGB && c != curColorARGB)
                {
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color), i, j, 1, 1);

                    FloodFill(bmp, color, i - 1, j);
                    FloodFill(bmp, color, i + 1, j);
                    FloodFill(bmp, color, i, j - 1);
                    FloodFill(bmp, color, i, j + 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

The starting point is always inside of the figure. I compare the colors by comparing their ARGB code that I acquire with toArgb method. For all the points that are on the left (i-1, j) or above (i, j-1) the toArgb method returns white color and the points get repainted, but for those who are on the right (i+1, j) or below (i, j+1) the method returns red for some reason and the point isn't filled and the points around don't get in stack. [The result is on the pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4qRT.png) What is its problem?..

UPD. After I changed DrawRectangle method to SetPixel, the algorithm works as it should, so I suppose, the problem was the drawing method. But I still don't have any idea why it happened.

Comment: You may want to compare [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290317/how-can-i-fill-part-of-image-with-color/45299760#45299760). Why use DrawRectangle instead of SetPixel? And why repeatedly create a Graphics object?

Comment: @TaW I changed "DrawRectangle" to "SetPixel", and it solved the problem. But I still would like to know why didn't DrawRectangle work. Thank you very much, I have no idea how to upvote a comment.

Comment: Sometimes, ie depending on the graphics and pen setting,  the drawing commands use antialiasing and this would break the floodfill comparisons.