# Detecting when mouse is over a hex grid object in a C# Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseover, onmousemove

Preface: I am not a programmer by trade. I just dabble.

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm making a simple hex map program, and I want to efficiently determine when the mouse moves over a hex element. I know I can create regions for form objects, but that seems inefficient. I decided to simply define square hit-boxes inside each element so I can use simple modulus operations and integer division to calculate the column and row numbers without having to use floating point math. Maybe I'm overthinking this back from the days when every CPU cycle mattered on my old 286, but I'd rather have my code be as efficient as possible.

Here is an image that shows a rough idea of where the numbers come from in the X dimension. The Y dimension is similar, but not illustrated. The red boxes aren't actually shown in the program. They are just an illustration of the size of the hit-box I chose:

[Hit-box illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEY4t.png)
(In the image, Xodd should be xOffsetOdd)

Here is the code I produced, and it seems to work well. I'm just wondering if there is a better method for doing this and if it would allow me to define the entire hex region without wasting too much CPU power. Note that this is just for my own personal use for building map images for later use. It doesn't have to be perfect, but I want it to be as good as possible.

```
        private void checkMapElementMouseOver(MouseEventArgs e, Bool overElement, int column, int row)
        {
            /*
             * Tile offests:
             * Column X increment 152
             * Column X-odd-offset 76
             * Row Y increment 68
             * Row Y-odd-offset 34
             */
            const int xPad = 10;    // Map tiles are inset
            const int yPad = 10;    // Map tiles are inset

            const int xStep = 152;  // Spacing between tile bounding boxes on a row
            const int xOffsetOdd = 76;  // Offset for tile bounding boxes on odd rows
            const int yStep = 68;   // Spacing between tile bounding boxes on a column
            const int yOffsetOdd = 34;  // Offset for tile bounding boxes on odd columns
            const int boxWidth = 56;    // Hit-box width
            const int boxHeight = 52;   // Hit-box height

            int xEven = e.X - xPad;
            int xOdd = e.X - xOffsetOdd - xPad;
            int yEven = e.Y - yPad;
            int yOdd = e.Y - yOffsetOdd - yPad;
            int modXEven = (xEven % xStep);
            int modXOdd = (xOdd % xStep);
            int modYEven = (yEven % yStep);
            int modYOdd = (yOdd % yStep);

            if ((modXEven >= 0) && (modXEven <= boxWidth) && (modYEven >= 0) && (modYEven <= boxHeight))
            {
                overElement = true; 
                column = 2 * (xEven / xStep);
                row = yEven / yStep;
            }
            else if ((modXOdd >= 0) && (modXOdd <= boxWidth) && (modYOdd >= 0) && (modYOdd <= boxHeight))
            {
                overElement = true;
                column = 1 + (2 * (xOdd / xStep));
                row = yOdd / yStep;
            }
            else
            {
                overElement = false;
                column = -1;
                row = -1;
            }
        }
```

Returning -1 for the row or column is just to indicate that I'm not over one of the hit-boxes. Those values are used to look up the element in my list/array variable.

Comment: I am rusty with Winforms but I think the Control.Region property lets you map a non-rectangular region on top of a control.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.region?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: @RickDavin The problem with that is I'm guessing that would require me to create one of those for every single hex space, which seems inefficient. Since my grid positions are static, I'm trying to "cheat" by treating the entire space like a simple checkerboard grid. My thinking is that an (X % Y) operation should be much easier on the CPU than whatever all the calculations are that a region control performs.

Comment: on the X Why don't just calculate with half of the xstep? Am i missing something? (e.X - xPad)%xtep. xtep = 76. Which is the xOffsetOdd.

Comment: @lork6 Because, for the odd columns, I need to use a different y value range. I'm basically taking the e.X (mouse value) and removing the left margin (xPad). Then I need to do the modulus with the full xStep of 152. For odd columns, I just shift them to the left by the xOffsetOdd and then they get treated just like the even columns from there. I consider the even columns first because they will always be staring with the top row. Odd columns always start on a row that is shifted down by yOffsetOdd.

The math works out. I'm just wondering if this is more efficient than other methods.

Comment: Question - is the user hovering over these regions in real time or are you only needing to know if they clicked in a tile?

Comment: @bdcoder Real time. That's why I care. If it was just onMouseClick, I wouldn't care about CPU cycles. This function is called on every MouseMove event for the PictureBox I'm using. I'm doing it this way because I thought about highlighting each hex spot as the mouse enters it.

Comment: I don't see much wrong with the way your going about it -- however, will you get false positives?  Looking at your illustration - specifically the last column - will the code generate a false positive if you hover above the square in the last column (as the pattern is not a "full" hex pattern?

Comment: @bdcoder That's where the next part of the program comes in. I check my list to see if that spot is populated. If the list returns null for that space, then I ignore it. This is me trying to deal with the fact that the Y values overlap between even and odd columns. Hex arrangement is messy to me. If you run through the code, the even and odd columns both return the same row number as you move down. They all fall in the same row in a 2D data array even though the odd columns are visually offset.

Comment: @John thanks for clearing up. then don't need to calculate 2 things for x. My idea is that you calculate the x one way. Then check if odd (xEven / xStep) % 2 = 0 you know the Y is in even or odd. Then calculate the rest. This way you calculate only what is need it.

Comment: Not sure if this would apply to your project - but it may: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/601952/how-can-i-detect-if-mouse-i-hover-picturebox-contr

Comment: @lork6 Yeah. Thanks. I wrote it this way to try to make it easier to understand. It's not fully optimized here. I'm really just trying to understand if the CONCEPT of using modulus calculations is reasonable or if I'm being dumb and there's some built-in "better" way to do it. I don't want to overthink it, but I imagined that there would be a lot of overhead from using regions and other stuff when I'm trying to do such a simple calculation.

Comment: @bdcoder Yeah. I looked at stuff like that, but I'm only using a single PictureBox. My calculations are based on where inside the PictureBox my mouse is. That led me down a rabbit hole of defining regions and stuff. Seemed a lot more complex than simple modulus and integer division.

Comment: I don't think there is a better way to do it. Even if the Region IsVisible func calculation is faster you need to check every Region. Other approach i can think of is Creating a custom Control which raise a event when the mouse is over. But I don't think is faster at some point let say 1000 Control is to much. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-windows-forms-control-mouseenter .

Comment: @lork6 Ok. Thanks. At least I'm not completely crazy here.

Comment: Other thing you can do if the problem is the mouse event raised too fast. Is to check a amount of time is elapsed. 50ms or so then only calculate the mouse pos. (DateTime.Now - Lasttime) > Timespan.frommillisec(50)

Comment: There is a way of doing it by cheating: create a colored copy of the grid and use GetPixel you test which color you are over.

Comment: @TaW Thank you! That's brilliant! I'll still do my modulus method, but I made a tile where the even numbered hex bits are white while the corner areas are black. Then, in the regions where there is overlap, I look up the color in tilespace to see if it is black or white. That will let me detect the full hexagon area without math for the diagonals. I just need to store one extra 2-bit 103x68 tile for the reference lookup.

Comment: I can't believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373615/create-custom-shape-for-button/28376826#28376826) was posted 9 years ago :-)